# Approximation of $\sum_{x \le k} \frac{\log(x)}{x}$

Tags: number-theory

Originally posted as a non-homework question. New to the site, and didn't know asking for homework advice was O.K. Anyways, here's what's going on:

I'm trying to show there exists a constant $B$ such that

$$
\sum_{x \le k} \frac{\log(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{2}\log^2(k) + B + O\left(\frac{\log(k)}{k}\right)
$$

I'm trying via partial summation to establish this. I think some of my trouble lies in understanding the question. If we're using the $O$ notation to bound an error term, and if we just need to show there exists a constant $B$ such that the above holds, why isn't $B$ absorbed into the error term?

Comment: Because $\log(k)/k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, a constant is not $O(\log(k)/k)$.

Comment: $B+O(\frac{\log k}{k})$ is not the same as $O(\frac{\log k}{k})$ because $(\log k)/k\to0$.

Comment: right of course. thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) gives this immediately because
$$
\int\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12\log(x)^2+C
$$
The constant $B$ dominates the error term $O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)$, so it is separate.